# AppDelegate in IOS fails when navigating to a page with SfDataGrid on it

Tags: xaml, xamarin, prism, syncfusion

i'm having problems with SfDataGrid on iOS that works fine on Android when i try to navigate to a page called "Hovedside" that has a SfDataGrid
it goes into `Main.cs` in the iOS part and fails on 
`UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace PrismUnityApp2.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

with this output:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.iOS.ExtendedScrollViewRenderer.WillMoveToWindow (UIKit.UIWindow window) [0x0000b] in <eee3a5d11e6d415a9b8017bfe242a045>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/3983064a/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3818/3983064a/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
at PrismUnityApp2.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00002] in C:\Users\asr\Desktop\GBS APP bakups\PrismUnityApp2 b4 scanner\PrismUnityApp2\PrismUnityApp2.iOS\Main.cs:20
```

There is nothing in the error list

if i remove the SfDataGrid then it navigates just fine to the page

i have the Required assemblies that syncfusion shows on
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatagrid/getting-started

i feel like im missing something in AppDelegate but can't find out what it may be

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Prism.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.iOS;

namespace PrismUnityApp2.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            SfDataGridRenderer.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App(new iOSInitializer()));
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }

    public class iOSInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

https://github.com/ZarpGitHub/PrismUnityApp-gbs

im using visual studio 2015 community, xamarin, prism v6.2.0 Xam.Plugin.Geolocator v3.0.4 and Syncfusion 14.3451.0.49.
mostly running it on a sony xperia z3 with Android version 6.0.1 and using 
API 23
i also use test it on a virtual iphone 6s plus IOS 10.0

Any help is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has already been fixed from our side. The fix will be available in our upcoming Volume 4 main release which is scheduled to be rolled by this week.

Regards,

Divakar.

Comment: Thank you very much Divakar
i finally updated and it worked great